# 1/f noise parameter characterization

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, estimation

I would like to characterize 1/f noise in some time series data. I would like to estimate the 1/f noise corner, and the standard deviation of the 1/f noise component and white noise component. The best thing I could find was this paper: [A generalized noise variance analysis model and
its application to the characterization of 1/f noise](http://www.biophot.caltech.edu/publications/pdf/mcdowell-2007-pink-noise-homodyne.pdf) that deals with photon noise arrival rates. That's great, I follow their math and everything. 
They start of with a random variable that is photon count rates. The problem is I want to do this for an ADC or electronic noise source and I'm not sure what my random variable would be. How do I estimate the 1/f noise corner, and the standard deviation of the 1/f noise component and white noise component with an electronic noise source from time series data?

To show what a 1/f noise spectrum looks like:
[image: http://electronicdesign.com/analog/understanding-noise-terms-electronic-circuits]

Here is what the FFT looks like. I'm hoping for something that is more numerical based than semi-empirically modeled.

[image]

Comment: what'sa *"$1/f$ noise corner"*?  and, exactly what do you want to do?  i am also not sure what you mean by *"characterize $1/f$ noise"*.  what is that?  are you *analyzing* an input as a R.V. or do you want to *generate* a R.V.?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson : My reading of it is there is noise being modelled as the addition of white noise and $1/f$ noise.  The "corner" frequency is that frequency at which the spectral density of the white noise overtakes that of the $1/f$ noise. OP can correct me if I'm wrong. :-)

Comment: yeah @PeterK., i started figuring that out.  i guess the OP can FFT several windowed frames of this signal.  do that several times and add or average the magnitude (or magnitude-squared).  then convert to dB. and fit a bilinear curve of dB to log-frequency to it.  it could be something like $$ \log \left(e^{\alpha (x-x_0)} + 1 \right) + y_0 $$  three parameters to fit.  for pink noise on the left, i think that $\alpha$ might be $-\frac12$.  $x_0$ would be the corner in log-frequency.

Comment: It would be simple to fit a line to my 1/f noise distribution if it were the continuously sampled version (ie, if I had the whole distribution). From the looks of the FFT this might be difficult to do, and probably not characterize the distribution well. I suppose I could re-sample the distribution if that kind of a method works with flicker noise. I'm hoping for a numerical solution.

Comment: first of all, the y-axis of the first plot should be labled "noise density in $20 \log(nV/\sqrt{Hz}) \ (dB)$ because it won't be a straight line on the left for pink or brown or whatever filtered noise.  second, you should, even with noise, window each frame with a decent window.  Hann or Hamming is good enough.  third, you should repeat this several times with the same window, but different noise data, toss phase information, and average the magnitude-squared before applying $10 \log(\text{mean}(|X[k]|^2))$ .  that should smooth things out.

Comment: and/or make your FFT much, much longer.

Comment: Can't make the FFT longer the data can't support a longer length.

Comment: If one accepts the 1/f-white noise hypothesis then the mathematical  modeling of the power spectrum is the Cin(x) function +constant white noise: http://dlmf.nist.gov/6.2 ; with scaling.  I believe this is the correct function for measuring the expected drift rate of 1/f.  It's been several years since I derived it and I might be remembering incorrectly.  But the idea is simple: with 1/f  you must have a starting measurement and then calculate how much you can expect to drift with time from the expected power addition given by 1/f .  If you need I can recreate the calculation.

Comment: Your suggesting to fit a Cin(x) function to the data parametrically? 
That could be a step forward for me, you would be able to model the white noise contribution.